# I want to show simple string in json with object name from web api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to show simple string in json with object name, how can add serialize object name one my below json result

```
 string dpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../dir/");
        string mainPath = dpath + id + "\\fil.pdf";

        byte[] pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(mainPath);
        string pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(pdfBase64, 
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
```

I want output like 
    file: "djkhfdjkfhkjdhkjhd" as josn

but now showing.
Unexpected 'd'

Comment: Your file should contain text in valid json format. Example `{ "text": "djkhfdjkfhkjdhkjhd"}`

Comment: setting the content-type header to "application/json" doesn't magically transform your data into JSON. It just tells the requesting application to _expect_ JSON. If you then don't send JSON, that's even worse. You need to use a JSON serialiser, which is built into Web API, if you return a strongly typed object instead of a custom response like this. Maybe take a tutorial?